# Как решить ошибку после запуска " npm run scss"

Tags: npm

packege.json
{
"name": "task_wp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"scss": "node-sass -watch scss -o css"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"node-sass": "^7.0.1"
}
}

после запуска npm run scss возникает конфликт такова формата `code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE' } npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! task_wp@1.0.0 scss:`node-sass -watch scss -o css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the task_wp@1.0.0 scss script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-27T21_00_11_150Z-debug.log
` не могу решить второй день. Полный ступор.

Comment: А из под администратора пробовали запускать и трижды перезагрузить компьютер?

Comment: а также купить лицензию на винду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"scss": "node-sass -watch scss -o css", тут непонятно "scss", наверно вы скопировали это из какого-нибудь источника, но не обратили внимание на то что это на самом деле путь к scss, то же самое и с css

"npm install node-sass" если не установлен

npm run node-sass "пусть к scss | sass/main.scss" "путь к css | css/style.css"

Comment: Спасибо, за совет "npm install node-sass" если не установлен и пути до этого я прописувала исходя ис корневий папки, ничего не помогает. Уже ни знаю что делать

Comment: Удалите строку "scripts", не пользуйтесь им, потому что не всегда scss и css могут быть в одной папке в проекте. Пользуйтесь командой которой я выше оставил "npm run node-sass *путь к scss* *путь к css*".
Пример: "npm run node-sass sass/style.scss css/style.css"

Comment: спасибо большое я сделала по вашей команде npm run node-sass "пусть к scss | sass/main.scss" "путь к css | css/style.css". И всьо заработала.

Comment: Но с с моей зборкой были проблеми так как она не обновлялась и файли устарели. Я на git hub нашла новый пакет сборки скачала установила и все сразу заработала.

Comment: я рад за вас, если я помог, сделайте мой ответ верным:)